# How do I get my mlab db to show up on my html page using angular and javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The fruit is just so I can make sure it works. Then I will make it work with mlab

Here is what I have in my html page I want it to show in.

```
<body ng-controller="PackingController as vm">

  <h2>List of fruits</h2>
  <li ng-repeat="fruit in vm.fruits">{{fruit}}</li>

</body>
```

In my packingcomponents.js page I have it like this.

```
class PackingController {
  constructor($http) {
    this.pack = "are you here";
    this.packing = $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/api/camp"
      //handels success
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;

      //handels errors
    }, function myError(response) {
      return response.statusText;

    });
    this.packinglist = this.packing;
    console.log(this.packing);
  }
}
```

Then last page I have is my angular_app.js page.

```
app.controller("PackingController", PackingController) 
this.hello = "world";
this.fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "berries"];
```

Right now I am trying to just get it to work then make it show my packing list on the page.

Comment: What is your controller name in html file??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AngularJs` Modify these part of codes:

1-Use this template for Your controllers

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module("app")
    .controller("PackingController", PackingController);

  /* @ngInject */
  function PackingController(factory) {
    var vm = this;
    //-------------------------------variables
    vm.fruits = [];
    //-------------------------------functions

    main();

    function main() {
      // call factory and get controller's data
    }
  }
})();
```

2-Modify your html codes

```html
<div ng-controller="PackingController as vm">
  <h2>List of fruits</h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in vm.fruits">{{fruit}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```